# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API : login process

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am doing a login process. After logging in, the homepage loads, but the `userID` is not updated without refreshing the page. I get the `userID` with

```
public class BaseController : ControllerBase
{
    public Guid? UserId => new(HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value);
}

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : BaseController
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginUserCommand command)
    {
        var res = await mediator.Send(command);

        return Ok(res);
    }
}

public class EntryController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("MainPageEntries")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetMainPageEntries(int page, int pageSize)
    {
        var entries = await mediator.Send(new GetMainPageEntriesQuery(UserId.Value, page, pageSize));

        return Ok(entries);
    }
}
```

It is calling the `GetMainPageEntries` action method after login. Here the user id is empty, but when I request it again (<kbd>F5</kbd>), it is full.

I want it to be filled when first loaded.

Comment: Could you please post the codes which is rleated with blazor client app call the GetMainPageEntries  after login and how you should the user ID.

Comment: Rather than using a property that is set when the object is created, you can use a method `GetUserId()` in your `BaseController`, which will be executed only when called.

Answer (score 1):

As Roy commented, you should get UserId in BaseController or User as shown below.

```
public AppUser User
{
    get
    {
         return new AppUser(this.User as ClaimsPrincipal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't just add answers that agree with something that someone else already said. The correct way to indicate agreement with a post is to upvote it.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine: What they agree with was stated in a comment, not a post.